# "Given token not valid for any token type" error in django when i send header with Authorization: None

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt

When I send request to my backend I got an error:

```json
{
    "detail": "Given token not valid for any token type",
    "code": "token_not_valid",
    "messages": [
        {
            "token_class": "AccessToken",
            "token_type": "access",
            "message": "Token is invalid or expired"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have this in views.py

```
class ProblemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Problem.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ProblemSerializer
    permission_classes = []

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(request.META)
        instance = self.get_object()
        user = request.user

        if user is not None and not user.is_anonymous:
            interaction, created = models.InteractionUserProblem.objects.get_or_create(user=user, problem=instance)

            if created:
                interaction.is_viewed = True
                interaction.save()

        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

and this in settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': ["rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication"],
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ['django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend'],
    "TEST_REQUEST_DEFAULT_FORMAT": "json",
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10,
}
```

From frontend comes header with Authorization: Bearer none if user is not authenticated.
I know solution to add `authentication_classes = []`, but I need authentication, to recognize user if he is authenticated. So how can I fix it, maybe I need to add some middleware?

I tried to add `authentication_classes = []`, but this is not solution for me. I need to catch Authorization: Bearer none somehow and process it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not send authorization header for not authenticated user.
If you have to send it, don't use `Authorization: "Bearer none"`, use just `Authorization: "none"` or anything else (I mean not starting with `Bearer`), this way backend will ignore this header and will not cause error.

UPD
If there is no way you can prevent frontend from sending this authorization header, you'd have to create custom authentication logic, like this:

```py
from rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication import JWTAuthentication
from rest_framework_simplejwt.exceptions import InvalidToken

class CustomJWTAuthentication(JWTAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        try:
            return super().authenticate(request)
        except InvalidToken:
            return None
```

and then in your settings:

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': ['path.to.CustomJWTAuthentication']
}
```

Comment: But i need to handle authenticated users and not authenticated ones. For auth ones i will send their activity on that ProblemView. This is the reason why from frontend I got same queries, but if user is not authenticated I got None token.

Comment: Please check updated answer for what might help then

Comment: Thanks i think that might work. Btw i fixed it too with custom middleware

Answer (score 0):

Problem might be fixed with custom middleware, which can fix invalid jwt token in request header.

```
def delete_none_token(get_response):
    def middleware(request):
        if "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION" in list(request.META.keys()):
            try:
                user = JWTAuthentication().authenticate(request)[0]
                request.user = user
            except:
                user = None
                print("wrong token")
            if not request.user.is_authenticated:
                request.META["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"] = ""
            if request.META["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"] == "Bearer none" or request.META["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"] == "Bearer ":
                request.META["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"] = ""
        response = get_response(request)
        return response
    return middleware
```